# Different shadow width for top, bottom, left and right

Tags: react-native

I've a card view with shadow. How can I differ the width of the shadow differently in top, bottom, right and left of the card?

```
const styles = {
  containerStyle: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 2,
    borderColor: '#ddd',
    borderBottomWidth: 0,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.1,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    elevation: 4,
    marginLeft: 15,
    marginRight: 15,
    marginTop: 5
  }
};
```

Comment: that does not usually happen, you can only set how much right or left and same for top and bottom, not for each individual direction.

Comment: Even that is not working. I'm testing in android device. shadowOffset is not working and setting elevation makes uniform shadow in all directions.

Comment: yes, on android shadow does not work, only elevation work.. a limitation of the platform. See if you can work around with the requirement otherwise a library is available for box shadow.

Answer (score 0):

I used [this library](https://github.com/879479119/react-native-shadow) for handle shadows in my react-native app.